# Problem spring boot application deployment to google app engine

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy spring boot application in to google cloud App engine environment , but it crashed and giving this error.

```
Bad configuration: Could not locate
 ....out\artifacts\tech_garoon_cloud_main\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
 Caused by:
 ...\out\artifacts\tech_garoon_cloud_main\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
 (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <threadsafe>false</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

My application folders structure

[image]

**So how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Hi Dev can you please the contents of appengine-web.xml?

Comment: Hi. I have added xml file in description. Thanks

Comment: **appengine-web.xml** seems fine .which version of appengine-gradle-plugin you are using?

Comment: @kamleshpandey in my project I use gradle 4.10

Comment: please try to use **appengine-gradle-plugin** version 2.0.0  or higher with gradle4.10. Try using **app.yaml** instead of **appengine-web.xml **.